# Rendering multiple images from Ruby on Rails 5 API application

Tags: angular5, ruby-on-rails-5, zip

I am currently developing an Angular 5 FrontEnd application communication with Ruby on Rails 5 BackEnd application. The functionality that I am working on right now is for the BackEnd server to return multiple images in one go to the front end these images are compressed in a zip file ( I can decompress them using zip gem) but I don't know how to render the images as an array of images or the second solution which is to render the zip file and let the front handle the decompressing I couldn't find a solution to decompress a received zip file from the BackEnd.
Thank you everyone.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev All heil Sergio our lord and savior.

Comment: Yes it worked :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send a JSON response with your images base64-encoded as strings in an array. Or an object. Whatever is more appropriate for your app/code.